# Problem checking out svn repo with subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have an svn repo that looks something like the following:

```
TRUNK/
     trials/  <- this is a java package
           <a bunch of java files>
```

When I check this out with eclipse through subclipse, I end up with a project with an empty src directory and a folder next to it called `trials`, which is not what I want. Is it possible to check it out through subclipse such that the src directory in the project contains trials which contains the java files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up solving this by rearranging the layout of the repository slightly (just put everything under a directory called "src") and after that subclipse just did the right thing (it's things like this that make me prefer a command line client where there is less magic, but not everyone on the team feels that way, so middle ground must be found).

Answer (score 1):

Try to check-out from Subeclipse using the use New > Other > SVN > Checkout Projects from SVN, and then use the "Checkout as a project in the workspace" option.

You can use the SVN Repository perspective to look at the repository to see if it has the files you need.